# head behaves differently between CLI and bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Have strange behaviour between running an interactive CLI vs. script under bash on RHEL 7.  The CLI behaves correctly but the bash script doesn't produce the same output.  What am I missing?

```
#! /bin/bash
JBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME:-"/opt/jboss/EAP-6.4.0"}
function jboss-cli {
    sudo $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "$1"
}

function check_jboss_status {
    set -x
    status=$(jboss-cli --command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' 2>&1 | head -n 1 | grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot')
    [ -z "$status" ] && has_exception=0 || has_exception=1
    echo $has_exception
    set +x
    exit 0  # <= strictly for testing
    return $has_exception
}
```

produces:

```
++ jboss-cli '--command=:read-attribute(name=server-state)'
++ head -n 1
++ grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot'
+ status=
++ jboss-cli '--command=:read-attribute(name=server-state)'
++ head -n 1
++ grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot'
+ echo

+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ has_exception=0
+ echo 0
0
+ set +x
```

whereas setting up my bash enviroment:

```
$ function jboss-cli { sudo $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "$1"; }
$ status=$(jboss-cli --command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' 2>&1 | head -n 1 | grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot')
$ [ -z "$status" ] && has_exception=0 || has_exception=1
$ echo $has_exception
1
```

EDIT:

Further testing shows that piping through head is the problem.  As my comment shows, removing that piped operation allows the function to behave properly in the script.  Is there something funky happening with pipes in this sequence or is head buggy?

EDIT #2: showing that the bash script works correctly on removing the pipe through head (i.e., I altered the original function):

```
status=$(jboss-cli --command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' 2>&1 | grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot')
```

Results in a successful grep:

```
+ check_jboss_status 
++ jboss-cli '--command=:read-attribute(name=server-state)'
++ grep -E -i -n 'CliInitializationException|System boot' 
+ status='2:org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller' 
+ '[' -z '2:org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller' ']' 
+ has_exception=1 
+ return 1 
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
```

Comment: What does `echo "$status"` show in the interactive case?

Comment: looks like the problem is piping the output through head...remove that and the command outputs to stdout.

Comment: How have you established that it is `head` that's behaving differently, rather than any of the other commands you're using?

Comment: The output shows that the commands work, it's just seems that the `grep` doesn't return anything.

Comment: *grumble* re: the title -- `head` is not part of bash, and it behaves *exactly* the same whether it's called from bash, dash, zsh, Python, Perl, C, etc. There is no such thing as "bash head".

Comment: The purpose of this function is to ensure jboss is listening for management commands.  jboss-cli is weak in implementation, throwing a runtime exception when jboss isn't running at all, which is different than if it's still booting up.  Both cases mean it's not operational, so I've built a wait function that relies on these messages...one to stderr and the other to stdout.  Seems the developers of jboss-cli expect interactive deployments, whereas I'm building a CD pipeline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy irrelevent to diagnosing the failure of head to operate the same in bash under two different invocations

Comment: @RobinCoe, it's intended to be relevant to selecting a title that isn't misleading, as opposed to one that presupposes such a thing as "bash head" exists.

Comment: @RobinCoe, ...as for the claim that there *exists* a failure of `head`, that's not yet demonstrated. Try piping through `tee out.$$` before the `head` part of the pipeline -- if you always have output with the exception there, but no output from the later `head` component (in both the success and failure scenarios), *then* there's enough information to pin the blame on head.

Comment: @RobinCoe, ...for all we know, `jboss-cli` could be deciding whether or not to log exceptions to the console at all (or to log some other status *before* the exception) depending on whether stderr is a TTY -- meaning that when `head | grep` doesn't find anything, there could well be nothing there to find.

Comment: @RobinCoe, ...if you generated a [mcve] by simplifying your program to no longer involve `jboss-cli`, by the way -- for instance, replacing it with `printf '%s\n' "CliInitializationException: yadda yadda"` -- that would go a long way towards reproducibility.

Comment: even better, `tee pre-head.$$ | head -n 1 | tee post-head.$$ | grep ...`, so you can compare `pre-head` and `post-head` data for each run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not sure how the operation with head in the pipeline could effect jboss-cli's output stream.  I've shown that the operation behaves successfully in a non-interactive shell just by removing the pipe through head.  I do like the idea of using tee to confirm the streams and will test that, but I do find the behaviour very stange.

Comment: @RobinCoe, honestly, my guess is that your CLI-driven and scripted-test scenarios differ in a way you haven't yet figured out, and which relates to JBoss and not to `head` at all -- but collecting logs with `tee` should make that more clear.

Comment: (BTW, the first tool I reach for in debugging this kind of scenario myself is [sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/), which basically acts as a high-performance full-system strace -- so you can get a record of *exactly* what was written by `jboss-cli`, *exactly* what was read by `head`, *exactly* what was written by `head`, *exactly* what was read by `grep`, etc).